# Not able to access the WorkOrder object in visualforce page. Throwing System.Visualforexecution exception

Tags: apex, visualforce, exception, work-order

I wrote following visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="WorkOrdersController" sidebar="true">
    <apex:repeat var="testWorkOrder" value="{!listOfRelatedWorkOrders}">
    <apex:outputText value  = " work orders :{!testWorkOrder}" />   
    </apex:repeat>  
</apex:page>
```

The `listOfRelatedWorkOrders` property is a `List<WorkOrder>` for the corresponding case but when I run is it gives me:

> System.VisualforceException: Read access denied for WorkOrder, controller action methods may not execute

I checked all the permission and everything is fine since user is administrator.

```
listOfRelatedWorkOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
listOfRelatedWorkOrders = [select Id from WorkOrder where CaseId =: fetchedCase.Id ];
```

Comment: Is the controller declared with `without sharing` annotation?

Comment: This is the signature : public class WorkOrdersController

Comment: Just because your user is an admin does *not* mean your permissions are high enough by default.

Comment: What are the API versions of your Visualforce page and controller extension? `WorkOrder` wasn't introduced until Spring '16 (API v 36.0)

Comment: Yeah I know so I checked every permission and everything was fine with all read write access

Comment: Should I change the page version to 36 since it is 34 right now

Comment: Hey @AdrianLarson thank you for pointing  out the version thing. I already changed the version of class but didn't change the vf page version. Never thought of changing of vf version.

Comment: Not me, that was @DerekF who picked that up. Did it fix your issue? If so he should post it as an answer.

Comment: Oh yes, Thanks for pointing out.  Thank you @DerekF. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that this was a matter of checking the API versions being used for the Visualforce page, and the controller extension.

The `WorkOrder` object was [introduced in Spring '16](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_api_objects_new.htm) (API v36.0), meaning that anything that references this object must have its API version set to at least 36.0

Trying to use an sObject defined in a later API version can throw some interesting errors. My brief reproduction tests ended up giving me

- On my test controller

  > Error: Entity is not API accessible
- On my test Visualforce page

  > Error: WorkOrder does not exist

Updating the API versions to at least 36.0 alleviated these issues for me.